# macOS Time Profiler profiling c++ code but can't find my function name

Tags: c++, macos, profiling, instruments

I wrote a simple test c++ code as my first trying with Time Profiler in my mac:

```cpp
#include <iostream>     // std::cout

int frank() { return 0; }

int main () {
  int a = frank();
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled it:

`g++ test.cpp -o test0`

And I use Time Profile to profile my executable file `test0`:

[image]

I thought I could find my function `frank()` in `Call Tree`, but I didn't.

Another question is how to pass arguments to an executable file in Time Profiler.

Comment: Most profilers work by sampling at a regular small intervals (statistical sampling). Your function `frank` is probably just too small (quick) to be caught by the sampler.  Try calling it inside a 0 to 1,000,000 loop.  Even then it might not be seen as it may just consist of 2 instructions.

Comment: Suppose your program takes 100 microseconds. Of that, about 99.999 are spent on I/O.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instruments is a sampling profiler for which the sample frequency is too low to detect your call to frank(). Either perform some computation-expensive calculation inside the function or simply call it a sufficient number of times.

Adjusting your code to the following (C++11) where a slightly more complex function is called within a loop:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout

long frank(const unsigned int n) { return n*n; }

int main () {
    const auto nr_iterations = 1000000u;
    long a;
    for (auto n = 0u; n < nr_iterations; ++n)
    {
        a = frank(n);
    }
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Results in the following result in Instruments on my machine:

[image]

To pass arguments via Instruments, click on the target name right next to the record button. In the context menu that appears, click 'Edit target’ where ‘target’ is your executable's name. For example:

[image]

A dialogue window appears where you can input the arguments.

Comment: I used your code and compiled it with `g++ test.cpp -o test0 --std=c++11`, but I still got the same Call Tree as before.

Comment: @Frank What happens if you increase nr_iterations? Say 10e6 for example

Comment: @Frank I've edited the code example to increase the likelihood of seeing the call within the profiler. Does this help?

Comment: When I run my code using instruments, the code executes in ~300msec but when I run it from the command line, it takes 12.5sec. I can see a function name in the profile from loading a file but the processing of the file doesn't seem to register. What's going on?